# Pandas - keep original spacing when merging two dataframes

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I'm wondering if when using the df.merge function, there is an option to keep the original spacing of the dataframes?

For example, if df1 looks like:

```
X     a b    C
```

and df2 like:

```
C         D
```

`df1.merge(df2, on=['C'])`

How do I get the merge function to produce the following:

```
X     a b    C         D
```

Comment: spacing isn't an attribute of your dataframe, right?

Comment: @coldspeed Right - it's not

Comment: there isn't really any way to maintain the spacing unless you set it again, manually.

Comment: @coldspeed I was afraid of that...thanks anyway